# RSA wrapper written in Kotlin

Tags: security, cryptography, kotlin

I've written up a small wrapper for RSA and AES encryption in Kotlin, and I want to make sure I'm not making any glaring mistakes before use it. This is going on a small project with basically no needed security, but I wanted to try and write it correctly.

Here's my `Person` class:

```
class Person private constructor(val name :String,
                  private val keyPair: KeyPair) {

    val publicKey : PublicKey
        get() = keyPair.public
    private val privateKey : PrivateKey
        get() = keyPair.private ?: error("Current Person implementation doesn't support functions that use the private key")

    fun isValid() = fromPrivateKey(name,privateKey).publicKey == publicKey

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Person(name=$name, finger=${fingerprint().substring(0,10)})"
    }


    fun sign(data :ByteArray): Signature {
        sig.initSign(privateKey)
        sig.update(data)
        return Signature(sig.sign())
    }

    fun fingerprint():String = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(publicKey.encoded)

    /** This needs to be below 245 bytes */
    fun encrypt(data :ByteArray, publicKey: PublicKey): ByteArray {
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA")
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey)
        return cipher.doFinal(data)
    }

    /** This needs to be below 245 bytes */
    fun encrypt(data :ByteArray, person :Person):ByteArray = encrypt(data,person.publicKey)

    /** This needs to be below 245 bytes */
    fun decrypt(encrypted: ByteArray): ByteArray {
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA")
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey)
        return cipher.doFinal(encrypted)
    }


    /** This will encrypt over 245 bytes */
    fun encryptAES(data :ByteArray,person :Person):EncryptedData = encryptAES(data,person.publicKey)

    /** This will encrypt over 245 bytes */
    fun encryptAES(data :ByteArray, publicKey : PublicKey): EncryptedData {
        val iv = ByteArray(16) { -1 }
        SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong().nextBytes(iv)

        val keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES")
        keyGen.init(128)
        val secretKey = keyGen.generateKey()


        val ivParameterSpec = IvParameterSpec(iv)
        val aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParameterSpec)

        val final = aesCipher.doFinal(data)
        return EncryptedData(iv, encrypt(secretKey.encoded,publicKey), final)
        //need to return encrypted secret key and the encrypted message
    }

    fun decryptAES(data : EncryptedData) :ByteArray{
        val iv = data.iv
        val ivParameterSpec = IvParameterSpec(iv)

        val decryptedSecretKey = decrypt(data.encryptedSecretKey)

        val secretKey = SecretKeySpec(decryptedSecretKey, 0, decryptedSecretKey.size, "AES")


        val aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParameterSpec)

        return aesCipher.doFinal(data.encryptedData)
    }
```

And then I use the Companion object to make new instances of this class:

```
companion object {
        private val sig = java.security.Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA")

        fun verify(publicKey: PublicKey, signature: Signature, data: ByteArray): Boolean {
            sig.initVerify(publicKey)
            sig.update(data)
            return sig.verify(signature.byteArray)
        }

        //buildKeyPair(DigestUtils.sha1(name)!!.contentHashCode().toLong())
        private fun buildKeyPair(seed :Long): KeyPair {
            val random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")
            random.setSeed(seed)
            val keySize = 2048
            val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA")
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(keySize,random)
            return keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair()
        }

        private fun buildKeyPair():KeyPair {
            val keySize = 2048
            val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA")
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(keySize)
            return keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair()
        }


        //generators
        fun fromKeyPair(name :String, keyPair: KeyPair):Person = Person(name, keyPair)
        fun fromPublicKey(name :String, publicKey: PublicKey):Person = Person(name,KeyPair(publicKey,null))
        fun fromPrivateKey(name :String, privateKey: PrivateKey):Person {
            //attempt to find the correct public key
            if(privateKey !is RSAPrivateCrtKey)
                error("Private key is not a RSAPrivateCrtKey and does not contain enough data to compute the public key")
            val spec = RSAPublicKeySpec(privateKey.modulus,privateKey.publicExponent)
            val factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
            val publicKey = factory.generatePublic(spec)
            return Person(name, KeyPair(publicKey,privateKey))
        }
        fun deterministicFromName(name :String) :Person = Person(name,buildKeyPair(DigestUtils.sha1(name)!!.contentHashCode().toLong()))
        fun generateNew(name :String) :Person = Person(name, buildKeyPair())
    }
```

This also uses these classes:

```
class Signature(val byteArray: ByteArray) {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as Signature

        if (!byteArray.contentEquals(other.byteArray)) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return byteArray.contentHashCode()
    }
}
```

and

```
class EncryptedData(val iv :ByteArray, val encryptedSecretKey :ByteArray,val encryptedData :ByteArray)
```

I'm using RSA keys to encrypt a randomly generated AES key, which can be used to encrypt data that is larger than 245 bytes.

The idea is that I can pass public keys around but treat everything as a `Person`, and then throw an error if the private key is invalid. Is this a good design?

Comment: The code formatting is inconsistent. You should let your IDE do the formatting for you, automatically whenevery you save the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most generic wrapper classes for crypto are used to *wrap* the knowledge of the user that wrote them, and this is no exception. Almost every line of cryptography in here is unfortunately below par. There is *no need* for the wrapper class *at all*, directly using the primitives is much better and will safe you from a maintainability nightmare.

I spend ages getting rid of my badly written wrapper classes in Java when I started crypto, inspired by the other - C++ based - wrapper *trash* written by my colleagues. I have been at this exact cross road, and I chose wrong. **Do not use this as generic class in your applications** unless you want to perform weeks of refactoring in the future (and that's not counting stupid bug fixes before that).

*If* you do not listen to this advice, please at least include a version number with your resulting signatures and encryption methods so you are able to upgrade/replace with something secure later on.

That all said, I do admire that you posted here and I do hope you keep your code here, if just to warn others. I hope you learn a lot. Use the knowledge you learn here to create classes for *specific use cases* instead.

---

Here is a line-by-line review for your learning experience.

```
class Person private constructor(val name :String, private val keyPair: KeyPair) {
```

What does a person have to do with the private key? Is it the owner maybe? Why is it not an entity? Can't a server have a key pair?

```
get() = keyPair.private ?: error("Current Person implementation doesn't support functions that use the private key")
```

How can you not have a private key in a key pair object? That doesn't make sense; just pass a public key in that case.

```
fun isValid() = fromPrivateKey(name,privateKey).publicKey == publicKey
```

I don't think it is all that funny if `isValid` is correct for some unexplained reason (or not).

```
return "Person(name=$name, finger=${fingerprint().substring(0,10)})"
```

Only later in the code it becomes clear that this is not a fingerprint of a person, but of the key. The 10 is a magic value, if you think that the fingerprint is smaller then you should let that be the result of the fingerprint calculation.

```
val aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
```

Why not a modern mode such as GCM?

```
val final = aesCipher.doFinal(data)
```

`final` is a terrible name for a variable, why not call it, say, `ciphertext`?

```
fun sign(data :ByteArray): Signature {
    sig.initSign(privateKey)
```

`sig` comes falling out of the sky, and it is unclear what kind of algorithm is used.

```
/** This needs to be below 245 bytes */
```

Seems to me that this depends on the key size and algorithm, both of which are undefined within the method. Better provide a helper method to retrieve the maximum size instead (`Cipher` has a helper function - `getOutputSize` - for that already). I presume you are going to write more documentation than just repeating this statement? And is this actually true for the data delivered for decryption?

```
fun encrypt(data :ByteArray, publicKey: PublicKey): ByteArray {
```

Why not use `RSAPublicKey` here? That way you don't get surprise exceptions late on.

```
fun fingerprint():String = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(publicKey.encoded)
```

Probably better to calculate the fingerprint over the modulus, that way the public and private key share the same fingerprint.

```
val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA")
```

Never relies on defaults like that. This is `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"` for the default Sun provider, but it could be another algorithm for different providers. OAEP padding should be preferred.

```
fun encryptAES(data :ByteArray, publicKey : PublicKey): EncryptedData {
```

Encryption with AES that takes a public key. This is definitely *not* a good name for the function. Just `encrypt` or `hybridEncrypt` would be better. Why is the public key passed if it is part of the fields of the object?

```
/** This will encrypt over 245 bytes */
```

And we're going to know in advance which method is chosen by the user I suppose? Wouldn't it also encrypt plaintext below that size?

```
val iv = ByteArray(16) { -1 }
```

Minus one. Just because we ... can?

```
SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong().nextBytes(iv)
```

Ah we use a strong random for the IV, which just needs to be unpredictable. Why? `SecureRandom` is strong enough. Blocking RNG's are not fun in any application.

```
keyGen.init(128)
```

Not wrong, but note that you're using the default `SecureRandom` here, so the key is less strong than the IV. Not that you should change this line.

```
//need to return encrypted secret key and the encrypted message
```

"returns" not "need to return" and put the comment before the actual `return` statement.

### On the companion object.

Why is there a companion object for signature generation, but not for encryption / decryption?

```
    private val sig = java.security.Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA")
```

SHA1 is completely insecure for signature generation.

```
 private fun buildKeyPair(seed :Long): KeyPair {
```

A long is 64 bits. It is becoming easy to try 2^64 values and simply regenerate the key pair. Or one of multiple key pairs if more are available. Why is a normal random not used?

```
val random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")
```

SHA1PRNG is not well defined, so this may return any kind of RNG. It may not be the best one either.

```
random.setSeed(seed)
```

Oh, boy. This may either mix in the seed or make the SHA1PRNG act deterministically. The outcome depends on a lot of factors. Java platform and version just being two of them. Use this and you're already borked.

```
val keySize = 2048
```

A rather small undefined, unexplained default and magic number. See keylength.com.

```
return keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair()
```

I'm pretty sure that method has been deprecated eons ago.

```
 val spec = RSAPublicKeySpec(privateKey.modulus,privateKey.publicExponent)
```

... but I'm not sure if the `publicExponent` is always available even for CRT private keys. Let's assume it is because it seems that way in the API (?).

```
 fun deterministicFromName(name :String) :Person = Person(name,buildKeyPair(DigestUtils.sha1(name)!!.contentHashCode().toLong()))
```

The private key is determined by the name using a publicly known, unkeyed algorithm. Wow. Just wow. Um, I'm flabbergasted.

RSA key pairs *must* be generated from random *unless* you can be 100% sure that the key pair generation (including prime number generation) *never changes*. For that, you'd need to include the entire RSA key pair generation *and random number generation* in your source code, or updates of the system may break your scheme.

And you should of course feed it a secret value containing enough (~128 bits of) entropy rather than a public value.

---

The signature and encryption classes are OK-ish, but remember: the idea of standardized signature and encryption algorithms is be able to communicate between runtimes. You'll have to think of some kind of serialization / protocol to do that.

Comment: Thanks! I have some comments and small additional questions, but I was 300 characters over the comment limit :(
Here is is:
https://hastebin.com/ivawuzexos.txt